# Javascript check if first element of tuple exists in array of tuples

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of tuples, where first element of tuple is string and second is int. Every tuple has array structure:

```
var array = [["ele1",1], ["ele2",1], ["ele3",1], ["ele4",1]];
```

How can I easily check if a string is element of a tuple in array of tuples in javascript?

```
if array.contains(tuple with first element "ele2")
```

Is it possible to do it without for loop (checking each element of array)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using a [relatively modern browser](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.some) you can just do this:

```
array.some(function(a) {
    return a[0] === 'string that you want';
})
```

or, more compactly:

```
array.some(a => a[0] === 'string that you want')
```

see [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1):

Might seem like a hack but still... :)

```
array.toString().split(',').indexOf('ele2') % 2 == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an 'easy way'. You will have to iterate through the array and do a check on every element:

```
var i = array.length, foo;
while (i--) {
   foo = array[i];
   if (foo[0] == 'ele2') {
       break; //success!
   }
}
```

Or the functional equivalent in the other answer.